# Hide optionmenu

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, optionmenu

I have a option Menu in my toolbar in app.but I want to Is unseen Some places.
What solution do you recommend to it my friends?

```
 Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

//codes...
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optionmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.item1) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image]

TO:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` method from activity.

Comment: I need a code to hide sometimes my optionmenu.Because I've used a lot View in a xml file!!

Answer (score 0):

try : Open menu xml using ctrl + click on `R.menu.optionmenu` in your code. Delete all "item" in xml, if you want to add menu items afterwards.
or
try : remove `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` from Activity if you don't want to use action bar menus at all.

Comment: I need a code to hide sometimes my optionmenu.Because I've used a lot View in a xml file!!

Comment: Can you update your question with xml file of menus?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this code and try again :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if("Your condition")
        {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.optionmenu, menu);
        }
        return true;
    }
```